# Why Docker build returned a non-zero code 2?

Tags: docker

My Dockerfile

```
Step 1/8 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> df5de72bdb3b
Step 2/8 : RUN apt update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 676c989bdccc

Step 3/8 : RUN apt install -y openssh-server
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ba531f318ac1
Step 4/8 : RUN useradd remote_user && echo "1234" | passwd remote_user stdin && mkidr /home/remote_user/.ssh && chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh
 ---> Running in 5ed475663a00
```

got error

```
The command '/bin/sh -c useradd remote_user && echo "1234" | passwd remote_user stdin && mkidr /home/remote_user/.ssh && chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I wanted to add pasword. Why it failed?

Comment: Add `set -x;` to the front of the command you RUN if you want trace logging so you can see how far it got before it failed. That said, `mkidr` will fail if nothing has previously because it's a typo.

Comment: (whether `passwd remote_user stdin` is correct usage would be something to look up in the man page for passwd in ubuntu:latest; that's effort that's presumably easier for you than me).

Comment: btw, have you considered putting the _hash_ of the password instead of the password's plaintext inside your Dockerfile? You can typically pass `useradd` the hash directly and not need to use the `passwd` command at all; and because dockerfile content isn't protected in a manner appropriate for password plaintext, you're also avoiding some serious security concerns that way. ("typically" because again, I haven't checked `man useradd` on ubuntu:latest; that's easier for you to do than me, if you're somewhere that's the primary distro y'all use)